# Смещение в таблице

Tags: вёрстка

Есть таблица, при вставке картинки да же самой маленькой в любую ячейку слетает вся таблица, т.е. не ровная будет. сам в верстке никогда не работал, прошу помощи, вот код:

```
<table cellpadding="25" cellspacing="5" align="center" cols="6" height="100%" rules="all" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <th class="click"></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th><img src="/elephant.gif" width="15" height"15"  /></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

чтобы таблица не "слетала" нужно задавать конкретные значения высоты и ширины для ячеек таблицы.

**upd**

```
<style>
th,td{
width:20px;
height:20px
}
</style>
```

Comment: подробнее....:(

Comment: [поподробнее....][1]
[1]:http://htmlbook.ru